# react context ternary operator returning true value all the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the code is being used for storing theme in localstorage dark or light.

```
let theme=AdminContext.AdminTheme;

theme ? 'dark' : 'light'
```

console.log(theme)  returns false;
but only dark is being returned

console.log(typeof(theme)) returns boolean

so what might be going wrong here

I tried giving false directly as parameter that was working properly..

Also I just started react So if you have any other suggestions please do help me

thnks in advance guys

App.js

```
`let theme=AdminContext.AdminTheme;
console.log(theme)
return (
<div className={`App ${theme ? 'dark' : 'light'}`}>
<Router basename='/reactadmin'>
<Switch>
<PublicRoute exact path='/(login)' component={AdminLogin}/>
<PrivateRoute component={PrivateRoutes} value={state} setState= 
{setState}/>
<Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
</Switch>
       
</Router>
  
</div>
```

Context

```
`import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext({
AdminId:localStorage.getItem('adminid') || null,
AdminName:localStorage.getItem('adminname') || null,
AdminType:localStorage.getItem('admintype') || null,
AdminToken:localStorage.getItem('admintoken') || null,
AdminUser:localStorage.getItem('adminuser') || null,
AdminProfile:localStorage.getItem('adminprofile') || null,
AdminProfile:localStorage.getItem('admintheme') || false,
removeAdminData: ()=>{},
Authenticate: ()=>{},
changeToken:(newToken)=>{},
setAdminData:(admindata)=>{},
toggleAdminTheme:()=>{}
});`
```

Global State For Context

```
state={
AdminId:localStorage.getItem('adminid') || null,
AdminName:localStorage.getItem('adminname') || null,
AdminType:localStorage.getItem('admintype') || null,
AdminToken:localStorage.getItem('admintoken') || null,
AdminUser:localStorage.getItem('adminuser') || null,
AdminProfile:localStorage.getItem('adminprofile') || null,
AdminTheme:localStorage.getItem('admintheme') || false,
}

toggleAdminTheme=()=>{
localStorage.setItem('admintheme',!this.state.AdminTheme);
this.setState({
AdminTheme:!this.state.AdminTheme,
});
}

render(){
return(
<AdminContext.Provider
value={{
AdminId: this.state.AdminId,
AdminName: this.state.AdminName,
AdminType:this.state.AdminType,
AdminToken:this.state.AdminToken,
AdminUser:this.state.AdminUser,
AdminProfile:this.state.AdminProfile,
AdminTheme:this.state.AdminTheme,
setAdminData:this.setAdminData,
removeAdminData:this.removeAdminData,
Authenticate:this.Authenticate,
changeToken:this.changeToken,
toggleAdminTheme:this.toggleAdminTheme,
}}
>
{this.props.children}
</AdminContext.Provider>
);
}
}`
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items stored in local storage are JSON strings, so when fetched/retrieved they need to be parsed. Both "true" and "false" are truthy values.

```
state={
  ...
  JSON.parse(AdminTheme:localStorage.getItem('admintheme')) || false,
}
```

Try it out in browser console

```
localStorage.setItem('test', false);
localStorage.getItem('test'); // "false"
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test')); // false
```